# Windows mingw graphical compiler

Tags: windows, c, programming, compiler

Is there a simple graphical(GUI) `mingw` compiler for windows that only lets us compile and return errors if any. I don't want a full-featured *IDE* I just need a compiler.

If there is any plug in that can interact with [atom](https://atom.io/) to accomplish this task it would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't recommend an IDE like Code Blocks

Comment: What do you mean by "graphical" - you don't want an IDE, but what do you want? To click on error & jump to the offending code? Or is it enough just to compile from the command line & see the output there?

Comment: I've never heard a "graphical compiler". All the compilers are command line applications, with the IDE or text editor do the calling under the hood if necessary